# Is there an alternate to seal (from unittest.mock) in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have following function that I want to write unit test for

```
def get_user_data(user, session):
    '''Given a github user, gets it data'''
    url = f'https://api.github.com/users/{user}'
    response = session.get(url)
    json_response = response.json()
    return json_response["login"]
```

This is how I am testing the above function

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, MagicMock
from requests import Session

response_payload = {"login": "agrawalo"}
fake_session = MagicMock(spec=Session)
fake_session.get.return_value.get_json.return_value = response_payload
```

If you notice the code above, instead of mocking "json" method on a response object I have created a mock for "get_json" method. This ends up creating get_json method on a response object. And now when I call

```
get_user_data("agrawalo", fake_session)
```

I get

```
<MagicMock name='mock.get().json().__getitem__()' id='139783470311800'>
```

Whereas I expect the above unittest to fail with NoAttributeError.

In python 3.8 there is a way to fix above problem using "seal" from unitest.mock.

```
# from python 3.8
from unittest.mock import seal
seal(fake_session)

get_user_data("agrawalo", fake_session)
```

How can I do this in python 2.7?

Comment: there's `autospec=True`, if you mock at the right level it should do nearly the same

Comment: also I assume when python3.8 gets released that the new features will be backported to `mock`

Comment: Mocking at the right level is a trick. Seal works recursively.